# Using (ugly) C code in C++ with extern "C"

Tags: c++, c

I face some problems with ugly written old C code.
I want to use a C++ compiler and use parts of this old code.

header.h

```
extern "C"{
int header();
}
```

header.c

```
#include "header.h"
int header(){
const int i=20;
int *ptr = &i;
}
```

This is compiling using gcc (4.9.3) with a warning (without the extern "C") but in g++ there is the error :
"invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]"

I am not directly interested in this code but want to know if there is a way of getting any working C code compiling with a C++ compiler?
(this is just an example what is "working" in C but not in C++ like the real problem is compiling with gcc but not with g++)

Comment: "if there is a way of getting any working C code compiling with a C++ compiler?" No, in spite of the declared goal to make C++ "a better C", the two ended up rather different languages.

Comment: Try not to make it harder then it needs to be.  As long as the C++ compiler sees the declaration of the C function with `extern "C"` then you can keep compiling it with a C compiler and the linker will be equally happy.

Comment: This is very bad code in both languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two alternatives:

1. Fix all errors that are not valid C++, or
2. Compile C files with gcc, and link them with C++ files

`extern "C"` only makes the C++ compiler to use C function names when it is calling the functions. If you choose to compile those functions with C++ compiler, it does not make those functions to actually compile with C rules.